# unable to apply profile LXC

Tags: lxc

I'm using LXC on Ubuntu Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, and I'm performing the following operations as unprivileged user.

```
$lxc config profile create privileged
$lxc config profile set privileged security.privileged true
```

I'm attempting to apply this profile to my container

```
  $ lxc profile apply my-lxc-ct privileged
    error: not found
```

Any idea on why I'm unable to apply this profile?